# Set Glue Code to External Libraries in Cucumber

Tags: cucumber, cucumber-java

We have multiple testing repos, and some of the scenarios depend on the steps already created in a separate repo, so I'm trying to build the JAR file and include it in the external libraries of the other repo. Then I define my gluecode in the IntelliJ runner with two separate lines:

```
com.edge.automation
C:\Users\MY_NAME\.m2\repository\com\reissue-automation\2.0.3-SNAPSHOT\reissue-automation-2.0.3-SNAPSHOT-tests.jar!\com.reissue.automation.stepdefinitions
```

IntelliJ is able to recognize the Gherkin sentence, but when I run it, it is throwing this exception:

```
eissueautomationstepdefinitions'
    at io.cucumber.core.options.CucumberPropertiesParser.parseAll(CucumberPropertiesParser.java:156)
    at io.cucumber.core.options.CucumberPropertiesParser.parse(CucumberPropertiesParser.java:88)
    at io.cucumber.core.cli.Main.run(Main.java:48)
    at io.cucumber.core.cli.Main.main(Main.java:33)
```

Does anybody know what this error means or if it's possible to include glue code from external libraries?

Comment: Cucumber looks for glue code in defined packages only (Cucumber options). So if you are putting them in external libraries it wont look for that. And the solution provided by you is the correct one only. Now, cucumber looks into the class path for glue code and it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up running the following command to copy my dependencies into the target folder which added it to the classpath.

```
mvn install dependency:copy-dependencies -DskipTests
```

Then it picked up the glue no problem.

```
com.edge.automation
com.reissue.automation.stepdefinitions
```

If anyone has a better solution feel free to post.

Answer (score 0):

May you add the detailed steps on how you accomplish it?
I tried running

mvn install dependency:copy-dependencies -DskipTests

And then running my maven command for running the test cases and not luck.

If you can add your folder structure and how you put it in the glue code of cucumber runner will be appreciated.
Also cucumber version might help.

Thanks